# Jquery Too Much Recursion Error

Tags: jquery, recursion, colors, jquery-animate

I hope someone could help me.

I have this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 spectrum();
 function spectrum(){
    $('#bottom-menu ul li.colored a').animate( { color: '#E7294F' }, 16000);
    spectrum2();
 }
 function spectrum2(){
    $('#bottom-menu ul li.colored a').animate( { color: '#3D423C' }, 16000);
    spectrum();
 }
});
</script>
```

it's working but when I look at firebug it says that there's a Too Much Recursion error.

I hope someone can tell me why.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your script never stops executing.

When the page loads, you tell it to run the function `spectrum()`. It runs this function, and is then told to run the function `spectrum2()`, which it does. When it finishes `spectrum2()`, you tell it to run `spectrum()` again, and when it's done that it has to run `spectrum2()` yet again.. see the pattern? Your poor script is stuck executing those two functions over and over, forever!

The process of a function calling itself (or two functions calling each-other repeatedly) is called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), but normally the recursion ultimately terminates in some way. Yours never terminates, so FireBug says "Wait a minute, this script is never going to end, I'd better throw an error!"

This probably isn't what you're trying to achieve, and the fix is most likely simple. If you could try and explain what you're trying to achieve, maybe we can help you write the proper code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a clear endless recursion. specturm() calls spectrum2() which in turn calls spectrum(); you do not have a condition for terminating. You need to add a condition to terminate that recursion. Perhaps you want to achieve the following. If you let us know what you are trying to achieve, then you will get a solution.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 spectrum();

 function spectrum(toEnd){
    $('#bottom-menu ul li.colored a').animate( { color: '#E7294F' }, 16000, function(){
     if(!toEnd)
        spectrum2(true);
     });
 }
 function spectrum2(toEnd){
    $('#bottom-menu ul li.colored a').animate( { color: '#3D423C' }, 16000, function(){

     if(!toEnd)
        spectrum(true);
    });
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the responses, I really appreciate them. 

About the code - I trying to make a menu item text blink, that's what I'm trying to achieve. spectrum() makes the text color a shade of black and spectrum2() makes it a shade of red. The code is actually working, I'm just bothered with the error found by firebug

Answer (score -1):

use setTimeout to remove the calling functions from the stack:

```
function spectrum(){
    $('#bottom-menu ul li.colored a').animate( { color: '#E7294F' }, 16000);
    setTimeout(function() {spectrum2();},100);
 }
```

this way, spectrum has a chance to finish while you start spectrum2. Do same with spectrum2.