# Jquery Firefox/Firebug recursion

Tags: jquery, firefox, recursion, firebug

I took this snippet and it works beautifully, but firefox/firebug are dying if the firebug console is on saying 'too much recursion.' Here is a post with a similar question that I don't feel was properly resolved [Jquery Too Much Recursion Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043970/jquery-too-much-recursion-error)

Is there a way to have this animation of colors cycle continuously without creating this recursion issue? If not, how can I get this to work without recursion? Specify an amount of time until end?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    spectrum();

    function spectrum(){
        var  hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' +  (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() *  256)) + ')';
        $('#welcome').animate( { backgroundColor: hue }, 1000);
        spectrum(); 
    }       
});
```

Comment: Don't use recursion when you just want to run a periodic task. try with setTimeout or similar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running that function as soon is it can, and not when the animation is completed. This causes the function to run probably hundreds of times every second, giving you the reccursion problem :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    spectrum();

    function spectrum(){
        var  hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' +  (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() *  256)) + ')';
        $('#welcome').animate( { backgroundColor: hue }, 1000, spectrum);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or simply: `$('#welcome').animate( { backgroundColor: hue }, 1000, spectrum);`... no need for another function.

Comment: @FelixKling - you're right as usual, edited it. Also a setInterval would be another way to go, but a callback is better IMO.

Comment: I was thinking about `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) as well, but since the animation should start again after the previous one finished, using the callback seems necessary. Also I'm pretty sure jQuery uses `setTimeout` internally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your recursive call is constantly being fired off instead of being fired after the animation in done. Instead put the call in the callback of the animate function like:

```
spectrum();
function spectrum() {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('#welcome').animate({
        backgroundColor: hue
    }, 1000, function() {
        spectrum();
    });
}​
```